# Read GeoTIFF file with php or javascript

Tags: javascript, geotiff-tiff, php, mysql

Sorry, I am newbie with GeoTIFF files.
I want to create a project that a person can upload a GeoTIFF file and the web application saves the lat/long of the picture into the database, the server side programming based on php and the database is MySQL.

Is there a library or a way to read and extract information of a GeoTIFF picture with php or javascript?

Comment: Are you sure you mean GeoTIFF, and not the location stored in a picture's EXIF tags? You can read the latter with PHP's [exif_read_data](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php "exif_read_data") function. If the file really is a GeoTIFF, this question's a duplicate of [How to read GeoTIFF using PHP?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/19589/how-to-read-geotiff-using-php "How to read GeoTIFF using PHP?").

Answer (score 3):

there is a php extension called php-gdal

I found some install instructions:
https://www.drupal.org/node/2133103

the main site: 
https://github.com/geonef/php5-gdal

helpful?
http://dl.maptools.org/dl/php_ogr/php_ogr_documentation.html

I looked at scruss' suggestion: ( [How to read GeoTIFF using PHP?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/19589/how-to-read-geotiff-using-php) ) and downloaded the code to take a look at.  I'm not convinced it is what you need.  Close, but I think you'll find yourself stripping most of the code away and possible need to add some of your own.  Best to try and find something pre-made.  Hopefully the php-gdal will work for you.  I have not tried it but use gdal in python regularly and it is great.

Be sure to let us know how it goes.

another possibility:
http://www.invet.net/images/catalog/creating_maps.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the location from the Geotiff header. Full documentation can be found at http://trac.osgeo.org/geotiff/ . I do not think it stores the center so you may have to take the 4 boundaries and average. You have a few choices including some APIS. as for direct read using javascript or php I do not know of a way. Anyway I think listgeo is a good starting point.

Comment: thank you for your attention , i searched any where and read many documents but cant find the solution,i just need the coordinate of boundaries

Comment: But this does have it, I have used it http://www.remotesensing.org/geotiff/listgeo.html It gives your the coordinates

Comment: sorry but i dont know how use it , perhabs this application based on windows , is there any example??