# Knowing byte address and byte length of "strip" in LZW-compressed GeoTiff with vanilla PHP?

Tags: geotiff-tiff, php, compression, specification, binary

I have a situation where I need to read cell values from a GeoTiff using vanilla PHP, and while I've been successful reading values from an uncompressed TIF (~800MB), I'm having difficulty reading values from the same TIF after LZW compression (~80MB).

I believe my trouble stems from knowing the byte address of a "strip" and the number of bytes belonging to that strip--as my understanding of LZW is that the decompression routine needs an entire strip, which it uses to create a translation table relative to that strip, before individual cell values represented in that strip can be interrogated.

Here's how I'm interpreting the [TIFF spec](ftp://ftp.remotesensing.org/pub/libtiff/doc/TIFF6.pdf): I can read the bytes for any "strip" by starting at the [Strip Offsets](http://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/tifftags/stripoffsets.html) tag value (fyi: my [RowsPerStrip](http://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/tifftags/rowsperstrip.html) tag value is 1), and getting the offset for the exact scanline I'm targeting like this:

`$stripOffset = $STRIP_OFFSETS + ($rowNum * 4); // i.e. 2 bytes per entry`

Then, to get the number of bytes I need to read ahead for my target strip/scanline, I do the same thing against the [StripByteCounts](http://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/tifftags/stripbytecounts.html) tag:

`$stripByteCount = $STRIP_BYTE_COUNTS + ($rowNum * 4); // also 2 bytes per entry`

With these values in hand, I thought I could then extract the entire strip

```
// Open the tiff file and point at the strip's byte address..
fseek($this->fp, $stripOffset);

// Read N bytes from the strip's byte address
$stripBytes = fread($this->fp, $stripByteCount);

// THESE BYTES SHOULD BE THE WHOLE STRIP, yes?
$strip_data = unpack('Vstrip_data', $stripBytes);
```

However, it seems like I'm getting more than one strip's worth of data--as what comes back begins with, and has several reoccurring instances of `128` in it, which should represent the so-called "ClearCode" mentioned in the spec.

> "The first code written is a ClearCode, which is defined to be code
>   256."

So my impression is that I'm either not correctly understanding how to evaluate a strip/scanline's byte address and/or byte count ..or ..I don't know!?! :) ..it's important to stress that, what comes back indeed starts with 128, which I am relatively certain is that ClearCode value. So I suspect I'm hitting the start of a strip, I'm just not grabbing a correct number of bytes.

Am I properly evaluating the byte address and number of bytes for a target strip/scanline?

And assuming no--what am I doing wrong here?

As mentioned--I've got this working with uncompressed TIFs by benefiting from [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/19589/how-to-read-geotiff-using-php), and [this code](http://www.osola.org.uk/elevations/index.htm), courtesy of Bob Osola. Therefore I'm certain my Easting/Northing → Column/Row translation is correct. And FWIW, my LZW compressed-TIF used a Predictor=2 (horizontal differenceing), although I do have a variation created with Predictor=1. That said, I don't believe the predictor is an issue in the context of this question.